# Where to put angular-cli.json content on Ionic 3 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3, videogular

I use [videogular2](https://videogular.github.io/videogular2/docs/modules/streaming/vg-hls/) with `Ionic 3` app. Can you tell me how can I do below kind of modification with ionic 3 app since it doesn't have `angular-cli.json`

I have installed it like so: `npm install hls.js --save`

*angular-cli.json*

```
{
        ...
        "apps": [
            {
                ...
                "scripts": [
                    "../node_modules/hls.js/dist/hls.min.js"
                ],
                ...
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
```

Error since I didn't do above:

```
console.js:35 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Hls is not defined
ReferenceError: Hls is not defined
    at VgHLS.webpackJsonp.1185.VgHLS.createPlayer (vg-hls.js:59)
    at VgHLS.webpackJsonp.1185.VgHLS.ngOnChanges (vg-hls.js:47)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12092)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13598)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (LiveEventVideo.html:73)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14339)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13508)
    at callViewAction (core.js:13858)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:13790)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13514)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14740)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14277)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11300)
    at NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM (nav-controller-base.js:460)
    at NavControllerBase._transition (nav-controller-base.js:540)
    at nav-controller-base.js:261
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4629)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:3)
    at p (polyfills.js:2)
    at IDBRequest.v (polyfills.js:2)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:223)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:216)
    at nav-controller-base.js:263
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4629)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:3)
    at p (polyfills.js:2)
    at IDBRequest.v (polyfills.js:2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need follow this steps:

1. Install / copy the JS files in to the project, you can use npm or
   copy to a specific folder.

```
    $ npm install videogular2 --save
    $ npm install @types/core-js --save-dev
    $ npm install hls.js --save
```

2. Add to your `package.json` this configuration:

```
 ...
"config": {   "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js" },
 ...
```

3. Create a file with the following path `ROOT_OF_YOUR_PROJECT/config/copy.config.js` & add the following:

```
    module.exports = {
        copyAssets: {
            src: ['{{SRC}}/assets/**/*'],
            dest: '{{WWW}}/assets'
        },
        copyIndexContent: {
            src: ['{{SRC}}/index.html', '{{SRC}}/manifest.json', '{{SRC}}/service-worker.js'],
            dest: '{{WWW}}'
        },
        copyFonts: {
            src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionicons/dist/fonts/**/*', '{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*'],
            dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/fonts'
        },
        copyPolyfills: {
            src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/ionic-angular/polyfills/polyfills.js'],
            dest: '{{BUILD}}'
        },
        copySwToolbox: {
            src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/sw-toolbox/sw-toolbox.js'],
            dest: '{{BUILD}}'
        },
        copyVideogularStyles: {
            src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/videogular2/fonts/videogular.css'],
            dest: '{{BUILD}}'
        },
        copyHlsScripts: {
            src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/hls.js/dist/hls.min.js'],
            dest: '{{BUILD}}'
        },
    }
```

Modify the file `src/index.html` to import your scripts & styles

```
<head>
...
    <link href="build/videogular.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="build/hls.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

## EDIT: Explanation

What we did here was to fix a problem known in Ionic which is for importing external assets ( scripts, styles, images ... ).

We added a little configration file in `package.json` which will force ionic to copy the `assets` we want in the build folder.

What is the build folder? The build folder is the folder generated in the runtime of the application. It contains your `artifects`. By default ionic doesn't include the assets in this build folder.

Why did we add the scripts & styles tag in `index.html`? It's simple what we did up to now was just copying the `assets` in the `build` folder. But we need to tell the application to use them. This is why we import them in the `index.html` too. Pay attention to path we used in the `index.html` it's the path where we copied our assets.

Comment: Have you worked with `videogular2`  on `ionic 3` app?

Comment: No. But if you want to import an external script, like your case. That's how you can do it.

Comment: I have a same named file on this path too `\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\config\copy.config.js`. So what will happen if I'll do above modification?

Comment: Why do I need this line `<script src="build/hls.min.js"></script>`?

Comment: How can I add this `style file`? Please see under the name **Adding the icon font** here: https://videogular.github.io/videogular2/docs/getting-started/

Comment: @Sampath I updated my answer to import also the styles. Just follow the instructions I mentionned above.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. But I would like to know about `what is happening here`? Hope you'll see above my comments too.

Comment: Now I have a better idea. But what happened the original `package.json` implementation due to our change? `"config": {
        "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
    },`. At this moment it is geting from here `\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\config\copy.config.js`

Comment: There can be multiples config\copy.config.js in your node_modules. But we need OUR config\copy.config.js to copy the assets we need.

Comment: Actually, we're overriding it no? Will it have any after effects if Ionic team will change that node module file in the future? i.e. Do we need to monitor the changes in node module file(`copy.config.js`) and copy the same thing to our file if it'll have new things in the future.

Comment: We're just copying the assets we want. But, if in the future Ionic team puts in place a better way of importing the assets then yes you need to change your code too.

Comment: It's a pleasure.